# Renaming files with adding a number to filename in bash

Tags: bash, rename, file-rename

I have lots of file like these:

```
13831_1.jpg
13838_1.jpg
138035_1.jpg
138037_1.jpg
138039_1.jpg
```

I need to add a value of 5000000 to the numbers of the filenames. 
The result should be the following:

```
5013831_1.jpg
5013838_1.jpg
5138035_1.jpg
5138037_1.jpg
5138039_1.jpg
```

Is there a way to do it with bash or perl?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do: `rename -v`. If it will output:

```
Usage: rename [-v] [-n] [-f] perlexpr [filenames]
```

This check is because there are at least two different rename tools, with very different functionalities. And the solution I'm having requires rename that handles perlexpr.

Then you can:

```
rename 's/^(\d+)/5000000+$1/e' *.jpg
```

Comment: I wanted to try this (as it sounds brilliant), but I don't seem to have `rename` in cygwin. You know if/how I could get it?

Comment: @SvendHansen, it's actually a [perl script](http://stackoverflow.org/wiki/Rename.pl).

Comment: I did a search on the internet, and it seems to not be available for cygwin. Installing the package `util-linux` will give you a `rename` command, but it works more like `mv` and doesn't seem to support regular expressions (or if it doesn't not in that format). There are some 3rd party/home written scripts out there to provide the functionality, though (like this one: http://nylinuxhelp.com/blogs/command-line/cygwin-rename-command-help)

Comment: Get the script - it's linked in doubleDown comment.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this using only `bash`

```
for file in *.jpg; do
  number=${file%_*}
  therest=${file#$number}
  mv "$file" "$((number+5000000))$therest"
done
```

Notes:

- `*.jpg` will expand to a list of `.jpg` files in current directory (ref: [Filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)).
- `${file%_*}` removes everything after `_` in the file name and return it. (ref: [Shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html))
- `${file#$number}` removes the content of variable `number` from the beginning of the file name and return it. (ref: [Shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html))
- `$((number+5000000))` evaluates the arithmetic expression inside and returns the result (ref: [Arithmetic expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion))

Answer (score -3):

```
$filename      = "13831_1.jpg";
$org           = explode("_".$filename);
$addnumber     = 5000000+$org[0];
$string        = implode("_",$addnumber);
```

Comment: what language it's in? it's definitely not bash.